# Xcode 9 - Bluetooth module HC-06

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, bluetooth

I am currently attempting to code for an iOS application on XCode and am currently having some issues.

Our group is connecting LED lights through a microcontroller and we need our iOS application to connect to the HC-06 Bluetooth module in order to control the LED lights on and off.

I only need to worry about the iOS side of the code not the microcontroller. I was just wondering how would I go about coding this on Xcode to send either a '1' or a '0' through Bluetooth to signal either 'on' or 'off' to the microcontroller?

Comment: Is this project absolutely required to use the HC-06 BT module? And, what does this question have to do with android?

Comment: Its what my group has in hand and we plan to use it with the ATMEGA32 micro. Would you suggest any other BT module?

Comment: All my research suggests that iOS is not compatible with HC-06. I quote " .... many new smartphones support only BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy or Bluetooth 4.0) instead of Bluetooth 2.0 or Bluetooth 1.0. The iPhone is most prominent of those smartphones as it’s supporting BLE since iPhone 4S"  From this website https://evothings.com/control-an-led-using-hm-10-ble-module-an-arduino-and-a-mobile-app/ .. Sorry not better news. Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can't use HC-06 BT or any Bluetooth 2.0 module because Apple uses [MFi license Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/)
You can use HM-10 BT module to control your microcontroller via Bluetooth Low Energy. 
You can read about BLE technology [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/introduction-to-bluetooth-low-energy/introduction).