# Connecting hc-05 with iPhone SE iOS(v11.0)

Tags: swift, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, iphone-se, hc-05

I have done some research on core bluetooth framework. Successfully setup discovery of peripheral of other iPhone, connect, discovered services and characteristics and write some values. All went well. Surprisingly come to know there is apple MIFI program (need to research on it).

In excitement I ordered iPhoneSE, HC-05 bluetooth module, Arduino Builder's Kit R2 with original Arduino UNO. It took some days/wasted in shipment and decent amount and now it's not working.

I write proper set up/initialization for peripheral and central classes, adopted delegates and I think it's all correct. However I am not able to connect to HC-05 bluetooth module.

**Observations**:

- On a Android device i turned on bluetooth in device settings, HC-05
  was able to be discovered, enter 0000/1234 (password as per
  documentation). And yes i was able to connect it. **It means HC-05 is
  not malfunctioning**.
- On a iPhoneSE iOS v11.0, Setting -> turn on bluetooth. But HC-05 is

  not discoverable.

I simply want to be successfully discover and connect to HC-05 module using BLE technology. Then with delegate methods look up services/characteristics and then try to on/off led.

I can provide more info and background if needed.

I need some help and direction so that I can purchase the correct bluetooth module which connect to iPhone, and I am sure I can do it.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are going to create a new tag, please edit the tag's info to make it useful.

Comment: I think you need HC-06 or HC-07 if connecting to iPhone - I can't remember where I read that, but will try and see. Apple implement different protocols/profiles.

Comment: @rmaddy sure will do it.

Comment: HM-10 https://stackoverflow.com/a/46486900/2836621

Answer (score 9):

To answer above question-
HC-05 will not connect iPhone. Because HC_05 is not bluetooth low energy.
I have used AT-09 from [amazon](https://www.amazon.in/Android-Bluetooth-arduino-Wireless-compatible/dp/B06Y65XG84/ref=as_sl_pc_qf_sp_asin_til?tag=alok0ec-21&linkCode=w00&linkId=a8a1e9758eaaccd7509b8819b633eed7&creativeASIN=B06Y65XG84).

I have written complete article how I achieved it [here](https://iosdose.com/iot-1-making-led-light-switch-on-and-off-using-at-09-ble-module-arduino-uno-iphone-se/), and challanges I faced with solution.

Answer (score 5):

The HC-05 isn't compatible with iOS.

This is because Apple uses MFi Licensing Program and HC-05 is not licensed.

To get things working go for a module supporting minimal BT Version V4.0 BLE. Even better, BT Version: V4.2 BLE & V5.0 (better range and larger packet-size), if iOS (v11.0) supports it.

I am not going to recommend a specific model, that's what Google is for.

Answer (score 2):

Apple devices under the MFi licensing scheme only support [limited profiles](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204387).

HC-05 is based on Bluetooth 2.0. What will work for Apple mobile devices (iPhone, iPad) will be those modules that utilise Bluetooth 4.0 or Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE).