# Why pybluez doesn't see MAC address of my phone in python?

Tags: macos, pybluez

when I enter `print(bluetooth.discover_devices())`, there isn't MAC address of my phone in console, although bluetooth is turned up in my phone. I want to know why this is happening.

Comment: I guess the bluetooth versions and/or profiles of the two devices do not match, but as you haven't disclosed what either device is, that will have to remain a guess... https://stackoverflow.com/q/50443456/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell, My phone is Samsung Galaxy S8, my computer is hp pavilion all-in-one 24-r0xx

Comment: So, try Googling your devices and seeing what version of Bluetooth and which profiles they each support.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I found out, that my phone uses version 5.0, my computer uses version 4.2. How to fix it?