# hc-05 bluetooth module data transfer in flutter

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, hc-05

I want to receive numerical data with bluetooth connection using hc-05 bluetooth module in flutter and show it on my application screen. How can I do this. I could not find a sample study.

I tried flutter's bluetooth libraries but could not get the result.

Comment: There are two types of Bluetooth which are commonly referred to as `Classic` and `BLE`. `HC05` uses `Classic` which is a problem if you are wanting to do Flutter on an Apple phone. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50444458/7721752